# how to upload a binary to google drive once compiled in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

Hello friends I am getting into the world of Jenkins, for my need is required to automate the process that once this all correct the jar or war is uploaded to a specific folder on google drive, this is possible ?

My jenkinsFile

```
"pipeline"{


"agent any
    tools"{
      "maven""MAVEN""jdk""Java11"
   }"stages"{
      "stage(""Clone the repo"")"{
         "steps"{
            "echo""Clone the repo""git credentialsId":"GitHub",
            "url":"https://github.com/xxxxxxxxxxx.git"
         }
      }"stage(""Maven Build SETTINGS"")"{
         "steps"{
            "withMaven( mavenSettingsConfig":"mvn-setting-xml"")"{
               "bat""mvn clean -U package"
            }
         }
      }"stage(""Quality gate"")"{
         "steps"{
            "echo""stage Quality gate here"
         }
      }"stage(""Unit Test"")"{
         "steps"{
            "echo""stage 3 here"
         }
      }"stage(""SonarQube Test"")"{
         "steps"{
            "echo""stage 4 here"
         }
      }"stage(""Deploy"")"{
         "steps"{
            "echo""deployment here"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Cloud Storage](https://plugins.jenkins.io/google-storage-plugin/) plugin for Jenkins. They have given a pretty comprehensive example on how to do it for freestyle project as well as declarative project. Copied here:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        CREDENTIALS_ID ='<YOUR_CREDENTIALS_ID>'
        BUCKET = '<YOUR_BUCKET_NAME>'
        PATTERN = '<OBJECT_TO_UPLOAD>'
    }
    stages{
        stage('Store to GCS') {
            steps{
                sh '''
                    env > build_environment.txt
                '''
                // If we name pattern build_environment.txt, this will upload the local file to our GCS bucket.
                step([$class: 'ClassicUploadStep', credentialsId: env
                        .CREDENTIALS_ID,  bucket: "gs://${env.BUCKET}",
                      pattern: env.PATTERN])
            }
        }
    }
```

One thing to note is that the credentials you set as `<YOUR_CREDENTIALS_ID>` are ones taken from the [Google OAuth Credentials](https://plugins.jenkins.io/google-oauth-plugin/) Plugin, so you need to install the plugin and set it up to serve your credentials. Both plugins have very descriptive documentation so make sure to read it all.